# Why would someone provide an empty default constructor for a class?

Tags: c++

```
class complex
{
  float x,y;
public:
  complex(){} //constructor with no arguments //what is use of giving such constructor
    complex(float z){x=y=z;}//constructor with 1 argument.
    complex(float real,float imag)
    {x=real;y=imag;}
    friend complex sum(complex,complex);
     friend void show(complex);
};

complex sum(complex c1,complex c2)
{
  complex c3;
  c3.x=c1.x+c2.x;
  c3.y=c1.y+c2.y;
  return (c3);
}

void show (complex c)
{
  cout<<c.x<<"+j"<<c.y<<"\n";
}
int main()
{
  complex p,q,r;
  p=complex(2.5,3.9);
  q=complex(1.6,2.5);
  r=sum(p,q);

  cout<<"p=";show(p);
  cout<<"q=";show(q);
  cout<<"r=";show(r);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not in this case, but you can set default values to the fields in it.

Comment: Note that it is usually a bad practice. You may end up with uninitialized objects if you forget to initialize them after construction, and then wonder what is going on. Better to initialize both fields to zero in the default constructor. The difference in performance is negligible.

Comment: @Sergey: Not if you want an array with ten million complex objects :P

Comment: @kotlinski Use a vector<complex>, reserve(10*1024*1024), and push_back(), and it will be as fast as the (unitialized) array without the danger. Why use pure C when you are programming in C++?!

Comment: @Sjoerd: Especially in embedded programming, it can be nice to use static arrays (placed in the BSS) rather than allocating dynamically on the heap.

Comment: @Kotlinski 80 MB static array?!? could be but it will not be common (note that Sergey used 'usually'). Even then, static arrays are initialized only once, hardly affecting performance - even if the compiler didn't optimize. So we're talking about a very rare case here - not exactly a good basis for a general rule.

Comment: @kotlinski: then, you have to provide the simplest complex class possible (see my answer) to be able to use it as POD, and have global/static objects default initialized.

Answer (score 28):

When you declare a class without any constructors, the compiler provides a default constructor (on demand) that default-initializes the members. (Note that default-initialization on built-ins such as `float` does nothing). However, once you define any constructor for the class, the default constructor is no longer automatically provided. Hence you must define your own default constructor if you still want one.

Comment: The answer is correct but not complete. We don't **have** to define default constructor in general case, even if some other constructor is already defined. But we must do it if we want to **use** it.

Comment: @FredOverflow Thanks for the fix. Looking back at it, I realize now that the implied "if you want it" might have been more subtle than I originally thought.

Comment: @user470379 two issues with the buffer overflow example.  The first is that shellcode does not contain null bytes.  The 2nd is that shell code is often syscalls,  such as `int 80` which can be used to open a file or execute a command.   ASLR was never intended to cause problems for shellcode,  its intended to prevent you from jumping to your shellcode in the first place.  Some ASLR implementations cause problem for ret2libc style attacks,  and with nx zones that causes problems.

Comment: @Rook Since you insist on bringing the issue up... please just stop and take a second to disassemble OP's shellcode ("\x6A\x21\xFF\x15\x40\x62\x40\x00\x83\xC4\x04\x6A\x0A\xFF\x15\x40\x62\x40\x00\x83\xC4\x04\xC3"). I don't care what shellcode is supposed to do, what it usually does, how it should b e written because I agree with you on that. However, ___look at this specific shellcode___ that OP is using. The second instruction in the shellcode uses an indirect far call ___using a hardcoded immediate value___ (presumably the entry in the executable's IAT for `puts` based on the comments). cont

Comment: @Rook If the linker option to set the PE header to enable ASLR ___on the executable itself___ is used, then the image base address can vary at runtime. Since the IAT location is based on an RVA in the PE structure, the IAT will move as well. A hardcoded far address (not relative) of an entry in the IAT will then not point to what OP thinks it does (and could possibly cause an access violation). However, it appears that by default on VS2K10 it is not enabled (which I was unsure of at the time). If you disagree, please point out specific parts that are incorrect.

Comment: @Rook Please note that I agree 100% that OP is getting the address of his shellcode and `ret`urning into it. The execution of the shellcode itself once OT `ret`s into it is what I'm discussing. Now in this specific case OP was getting the access violation because the NX bit was set on the page holding the data section of the executable. I mentioned this as a possibility (mistakenly saying it was the stack as I wasn't being careful and in the real world this shellcode will usually be on the stack not a literal in the data section), then I also mentioned the hardcoded absolute address as well.

Comment: @Rook I appreciate and gladly welcome constructive criticism, but merely dismissing me out of hand and saying I have no clue what I'm talking about doesn't help you, me, or anybody else. If I'm mistaken, please tell me where so I can learn more. Please don't mistake my emphasis above for yelling/anger, I'm just trying to attract your attention to specific parts.

Comment: @Rook Also, while I'm not the one who mentioned NULL bytes in the shellcode, this statement: "That shellcode does not contain null bytes." is patently false. `buffer[7]` is in fact a null byte. While I realize that shellcode shouldn't contain, usually doesn't contain, probably won't work if it contains NULL bytes, the shellcode provided by OP __does in fact have NULL bytes,__ no two ways about it.

Comment: I mistakenly mentioned far calls several times above, what I meant was near calls to absolute addresses.

Answer (score 16):

This is a codeified and corrected version of [@user470379's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482113/what-is-do-nothing-constructor/4482140#4482140)

Consider the empty class:

```
class complex
{
    float x,y;
};
```

The compiler actually generates several functions for this class for you, even if they are not declared. The compiler generated functions make the class *really* look like this:

```
class complex
{
    float x,y;
public:
    complex(); //Compiler generated functions
    complex(const complex&);
    complex& operator=(const complex&);
    ~complex();
};
```

Now, you take your complex class, and you add your constructor taking a `float`. When you do this, you tell C++ that you do not want the compiler provided default constructor:

```
class complex
{
    float x,y;
public:
    // complex(); //No longer generated
    //Don't forget explicit here unless you want implicit conversions
    //from `float`
    explicit complex(float z) {x=y=z;} //User defined constructor
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Compiler generated functions
    complex(const complex&);  //Note copy constructor and copy assignment
                              //operator are still generated.
    complex& operator=(const complex&);
    ~complex();
};
```

Now, whenever anyone wants a `complex` they *must* provide the `float` parameter. For example, the following code is now illegal:

```
int main()
{
    complex c; //ERROR! No default constructor available.
    complex g(4.2f); //Ok; float parameter specified.
}
```

If you want your user to be able to just construct a `complex` without supplying the `float` parameter, you must then explicitly create the constructor:

```
class complex
{
    float x,y;
public:
    complex() {} //Allow default construction of `complex` objects.
    //Don't forget explicit here unless you want implicit conversions
    //from `float`
    explicit complex(float z) {x=y=z;}
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    complex(const complex&);  //Compiler generated functions
    complex& operator=(const complex&);
    ~complex();
};
```

Now the user can default-construct a `complex` object anywhere they please.

Comment: @Billy: Perhaps add a comment (even though it's visible in the code) that the copy constructor is generated nonetheless ?

Comment: `x=y=z;` should be `x=z; y=0;` to match the the usual mathematical approach.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Yes, that is correct. I just did that because that's what the OP's code is. (And actually, it would be better to use the initializer list than the assignments in any case)

Comment: so is it basically ..if we wants to add constructor with arguments of type object then compiler don't provide it implicitly and we have to do that task by providing it explicitly??..am i correct?..

Comment: You only need `struct complex { complex(float x = 0., float y = 0.) : x(x), y(y) {} private: float x, y; };` to match 1) standard embedding of real numbers in complex numbers 2) the standard behavior of default-initialization of built in types.

Comment: @Trupti: If you provide *any* constructor, the compiler will no longer provide the default one, yes. (Not sure what you mean by "arguments of type object")

Answer (score 2):

**Because some programmers haven't upgraded their habits to modern standards.**

Back in the old C days (pre C-99), one had to declare variables at the top of a block, and thus declaration and initialisation were frequently separated.

In modern C++, there is barely ever a good reason not to declare and initialize in the same statement.

As a result, it should be an exception and not the rule to provide a default constructor.

Comment: While in general I agree that providing the empty default constructor for the sole purpose of allowing definitions at the top of the block is bad (+1), there are plenty of cases to define one even without this. For example, if someone wants any of the standard container `resize()` methods to work. Additionally, there are plenty of cases where it makes sense to define a default value (For example, in `complex` that should probably be `0.0f`), in which cases a default constructor should be provided.

Comment: @Billy There aren't that many cases where a default constructor has a logically sound interpretation; complex is one of the exceptions. And even in the case of complex, I prefer `complex c = 0;` over `complex c;`. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with the fact that default constructors should be frowned upon if there is no canonical meaning to them (complex numbers should have a default constructor that makes them zero, to mimic built in types semantics), there are a few scenarios where they are mandatory. Quite a few standard library constructs mandate default constructible objects, especially iterators and containers' value types (at least for some methods: `resize` for instance).

Sometimes, you may want objects (or are forced by the standard to want) to have a "null" state, which is only reachable by a default constructor. Then you have to write [safe bool idioms](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html), use smart pointers and pimpl idioms, etc. This can be good, or not.

I agree, it is not good practice to add the complexity of null states (and the errors they can induce) to objects which don't need them, but sometimes, you are forced to.

For the record, complex classes should look like:

```
struct complex
{
    // Allow default initialization, and standard embedding
    // of real numbers in complex numbers
    complex(float real = 0., float imag = 0.) 
        : real(real), imag(imag) 
    {}

    float real, imag; // no need for privacy here
};

// Operators are defined outside the class
complex operator+(complex x, complex y) 
{
    return complex(x.real + y.real, x.imag + y.imag);
}

// etc

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, complex x)
{
    return os << x.real << " + i" << x.imag;
}
```

Note that since `complex` is a POD type, you should even be able to do `complex x = { 2., 3. };` and have them zero-initialized for you in static arrays.

Comment: According to C++98, complex is not a POD: It has a user-defined constructor. Yes, I agree that is overly restrictive, and so do the experts: In the new C++0x, I believe it is a POD (or whatever it is called in that standard). I guess you're relying on a gcc-extension for `complex x = { 2., 3. };`.

Comment: Another small nitpic: the operators should use const complex&. Although I guess the compiler will optimize away all copies anyway. But I agree on the general approach (so +1).

Comment: @sjoerd: passing by value or by reference is likely to yield exactly the same code here.

Answer (score 0):

Working with the C++ Standard Library usually requries your classes to have no-arg constructor (like in: `vector<complex> vc(6);`).

Creating arrays either stack-allocated (`complex arcmpl[20];`) or dynamically allocated (`complex * dynarcmplx = new complex[n];`) as well calls no-arg constructors.

As it was said before, if you define any constructor for your class, you have no more (compiler generated no-arg) “default constructor” and in this case if you want to write something like I mentioned above, you should provide your own no-arg constructor.

Comment: All the examples you give, have problems associated with them: Stack allocated arrays are rare as they cannot have a dynamic determined size; new[] has exception-safety problems (if you solve them correctly, you'll have remade half of std::vector). And making explicit the values to which your vector is initialized is a good practice: `vector<complex> vc(6, complex(0,0));`

Answer (score 0):

Providing an empty default constructor(**`private`**) is necessary in those cases when you don't want an object of the class in the whole program.

For e.g. the class given below will have a compiler generated default empty constructor as a **`public member`**. As a result, you can make an object of such a class.

```
class test1
{
public:
int a;
};
int main()
{
test1 var; //compiles without an error.
}
```

However, if you want to stop anyone from constructing an object of the class, you can add an empty constructor as a **`private member`**. For e.g.

```
class test2
{
test2(){}
public:
int a;
};

int main()
{
test2 var; // This will give an error
}
```

> abc.cpp: In function âint main()â: abc.cpp:10:9: error:
>   âtest2::test2()â is private within this context    test2 var; // This
>   will give an error
>            ^~~ abc.cpp:3:3: note: declared private here    test2(){}    ^~~~~

You'll get an error if you try to run the above program because by design the 'test2' class is not supposed to have an object.