# error 2d vector class initialization in class

Tags: c++, class, vector, constructor

I defined the class `Brique`. The constructor accepts a `forme` and `couleur` as follows:

```
class Brique
{
private:
  Forme   forme   ;
  Couleur couleur ;

public:
Brique(Forme _forme, Couleur _couleur)
    :forme(_forme), couleur(_couleur) {}
};
```

I have defined a new class called `Construction` which constructor should use a class `Brique` to initialize a vector of 1x1. But when I compiled I got this error :

> error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘std::vector::vector(Brique&)’
>   :contenu(1,vector(brique)){}

Code of class `Construction`:

```
class Construction
{
  private:
    vector<vector<Brique> > contenu;

  public:
    Construction(Brique& brique)
    :contenu(1,vector<Brique>(brique)){}

};
```

here is the main

```
int main()
{
  Brique test("square", "red");
  Construction temp(test);  
  return 0;
}
```

I know how to initialize vector using pointers like this:

```
  vec.push_back(new Brique(test) )
```

but this creates a new instances and I want to use only references to my instance `test`.

Comment: You are missing a `)` in `contenu(1,vector<Brique>(brique)` but that should be a different error.

Comment: Also you will need a zero-parameters (maybe just empty) default constructor for your class since you created your own. More info on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482113/why-would-someone-provide-an-empty-default-constructor-for-a-class

Comment: You also need to check double check the [available constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) `std::vector` has.

Comment: Brique class should not have any default constructor. Problem conditions.

Comment: I can only use iostream, vector and string. I will try with vector of pointers and  push_back a pointer to instance test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class `Construction` you are initialising the field `contenu` incorrectly. You mention that you want to initialise it as a 1x1 `std::vector` in the constructor. To do this you must use constructor **(2)** referenced in the [`std::vector::vector` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

So, try the following instead:

```
class Construction {
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<Brique>> contenu;
public:
    Construction(const Brique& brique)
        : contenu(1, std::vector<Brique>(1, brique)) {}
};
```

That will set `contenu` to a 1x1 "matrix" containing the value of `brique` initially.